# Apache Ignite cache "IN" clause not working

Tags: java, ignite

What I want to do is

```
    final String query = "select userName from users where userId  in
         (?) and isActive = 1";
            SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery(query);
            List<Long> userIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
            userIds.add(140l);
            userIds.add(245l);

            sql.setArgs(userIds.toArray());
            List<List<?>> rsList = usersCache.query(sql).getAll();
```

. It is not giving the desired result. It is returning only one result
instead of two.
Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to pass an array as an argument for `in`. You can rewrite your query to use a join instead. It will look as follows:

```sql
select u.userName from users u 
    join table (userId bigint=?) t on u.userId=t.userId 
where u.isActive=1
```

Another thing you should take into account is that `SqlFieldsQuery.setArgs(...)` takes a vararg as an argument. So, to prevent your array from being unfolded, you should add a cast to `Object`:

```java
sql.setArgs((Object)userIds.toArray());
```